# MAX & MIN Value on GridView Column VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, winforms, devexpress

I am developing a small program to get the maximum of a specific column in a gridview (DevExpress), but I could not execute it as I wanted.

Can you support me in seeing where I have the error?

```
    Dim cells() As GridCell = GridView2.GetSelectedCells()
    Dim values As New List(Of Decimal)()
    For i As Integer = 0 To GridView2.RowCount - 1
        Dim value As Decimal = Convert.ToDecimal(GridView2.GetRowCellValue(cells(i).RowHandle, cells(i).Column))
        values.Add(value)
    Next i
    values.Sort()

    MsgBox(values.Max().ToString())
```

Regards.

Comment: _I could not execute it as I wanted_, we don't know what you want. What you see? Are getting an exception?

Comment: @Fabio, Get the MAX value of column. This is the error: System.IndexOutOfRangeException: 'Index was outside the bounds of the array.'

Comment: What value is in `i` variable?

Comment: @Fabio, I think the values do not reach i, I think they go to 0

Comment: _Index was outside the bounds of the array_ - where in your code sample you are using an index to get values from array?

Comment: @Fabio, No, just the i

Comment: So what is `i` representing? is this a random number, or something else?

Comment: @Fabio, no I want to get all values of a Column specific and after this, get the MAX of this values

Comment: To find a reason for System.IndexOutOfRangeException with message _Index was outside the bounds of the array_ you need to find out what values are in `i` when code iterating all rows in gridview and where you are using this `i` variable and why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the built in DataGridView, the number of rows can be Rows.Count -2 because there is an extra row for the user to enter a new record. I have no idea if DevExpress works that way but it is worth a try.

```
For i As Integer = 0 To GridView2.RowCount - 2
```

If your GridView uses a DataTable as a DataSource, then the following code might help. If the DataTable is still available then just start with that. Otherwise extract it from the grid.

DataTable does not implement IEnumerable but there is an extension method to get the interface (.AsEnumerable).

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim dt = DirectCast(DataGridView1.DataSource, DataTable)
    Dim maxValue = Aggregate r In dt.AsEnumerable
                   Into MaxID = Max(r("ID"))   '"ID" is the name of a column
    MessageBox.Show(maxValue.ToString)
End Sub
```

Same thing for Min just change Max to Min.

Answer (score 1):

Calculate Total Summary for Grid Column

```
gridView1.Columns("UnitsInStock").Summary.Add(DevExpress.Data.SummaryItemType.Average, "UnitsInStock", "Avg={0:n2}")
gridView1.Columns("UnitsInStock").Summary.Add(DevExpress.Data.SummaryItemType.Sum, "UnitsInStock", "Sum={0}")
Dim item As GridColumnSummaryItem = New GridColumnSummaryItem(DevExpress.Data.SummaryItemType.Max, "UnitsInStock", "Max={0}")
gridView1.Columns("UnitsInStock").Summary.Add(item)
```

[image]

Devexpress Documentation:

https://documentation.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/DevExpress.XtraGrid.Columns.GridColumn.Summary.property

https://documentation.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/9677/Controls-and-Libraries/Data-Grid/Examples/Summaries/How-to-Calculate-Single-Total-Summary-for-Grid-s-Column